# Understanding coderbyte back-end challenge

Tags: php

This is the challenge: In the PHP file, write a program to perform a GET request on the route https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting which contains a data key and the value is a string which contains items in the format: key=STRING, age=INTEGER. Your goal is to count how many items exist that have an age equal to or greater than 50, and print this final value.

Example Input
{"data":"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47"}

Once your function is working, take the final output string and replace all characters that appear in your ChallengeToken with --[CHAR]--.

Your ChallengeToken: ndv946kie1

Here's my code:

```
<?PHP 

$ch = curl_init('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//print_r(json_decode($data, true));
$arr = json_decode($data, true);
$items = explode(', ', $arr['data']);
$count = 0;

foreach ($items as $item){
 //print_r($item . PHP_EOL);
 if(str_starts_with($item,'age=')===true){
   $age = explode('=',$item)[1];
   if($age >= 50)
     $count++;
   }
}

$str = 'ndv946kie1';
$chars = str_split($str);
$final = '';
foreach ($chars as $char){
   $final = $final . $count;
}
print_r($final);
?>
```

coderbyte says incorrect output, maybe I misunderstood the last instruction?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the solution as below and its working fine.

```
<?php
      $ch = curl_init('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  //print_r(json_decode($data, true));
  //converting input data into array 
  $newdata=json_decode($data, true);
  // reading the array from data and exploding the value and storing it in the new variable 
  $newdataset= explode(', ',$newdata['data']);
  $count=0; // to get the count
  foreach($newdataset as $keyvalue){ //looping through all the input
    $age=trim(explode('=',$keyvalue)[1]); // getting value of each element
    if(is_numeric($age) && $age>=50){ // checking weather the value is numeric and grater than 50
      $count++;// increment the count
    }
  }
  echo $count;
?>
```

Note: it will not work in case if the key value is numeric and greater than 50(key=IAfpK, age=58) .

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem...
Giving below the code that worked for me:

```
    <?php 
$ch = curl_init('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//print_r(json_decode($data, true));
$arr = json_decode($data, true);
$items = explode(', ', $arr['data']);
$count = 0;

foreach ($items as $item){
 //print_r($item . PHP_EOL);
 if(str_starts_with($item,'age=')===true){
   $age = explode('=',$item)[1];
   if($age >= 50)
     $count++;
   }
}

print_r($count);
?>
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide some details or explanation of why your code is correct. Also, not sure if relevant but your code does not satisfy the last requirement of the prompt: "Once your function is working, take the final output string and replace all characters that appear in your ChallengeToken with --[CHAR]--."

Answer (score -1):

Please try with this

```php
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json_data = json_decode($data, true);
$items = explode(', ', $json_data['data']);
$count = array_reduce($items, function ($count, $item) {
  if (strpos($item, 'age=') !== false) {
    $age = explode('=', $item)[1];
    if ($age >= 50) return $count + 1;
  }
  return $count;
}, 0);

print_r($count);
```

Comment: Please provide reason _why_ the asking person should be pleased by trying something.  E.g. what is different to the code asked about and why does it make a difference.